# Create and login program in JavaFX (arrays)

Tags: java, arrays, javafx

So i want to create a program that creates a new account for the user, and the user should be able to 'login' with that same account. Now, i already managed to do the first part (create an account with arrays), but now i don't know how to login with that account.

PS: when i say login, it's just an alertbox that pops up

Here's the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField ;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Login extends Application {

    Button btnAanmaken,btnInloggen;
    TextField txtUsername;
    PasswordField Password;
    Label lblUsername,lblPassword;
    int index;
    String[] user = new String[10];
    String[] pas = new String[10];


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Aanmelden");


        btnAanmaken = new Button();
        btnAanmaken.setText("Aanmaken");

        btnInloggen = new Button();
        btnInloggen.setText("Inloggen");

        txtUsername=new TextField();
        txtUsername.setMaxWidth(200);

        Password=new PasswordField();
        Password.setMaxWidth(200);

        lblUsername=new Label();
        lblUsername.setText("Gebruikersnaam");

        lblPassword=new Label();
        lblPassword.setText("Paswoord");

       btnAanmaken.setOnAction(e ->{
           if (index < 10){
            index++;  
            user[index]=txtUsername.getText();
            pas[index]=Password.getText();

           AlertBox.display("Accountdetails","Account werd succesvol aangemaakt: \n Gebruikersnaam: " + user[index] + " \n Paswoord: " + pas[index]  );
           txtUsername.clear();
           Password.clear();
       }else{
           AlertBox.display("Error", "U heeft het maximaal aantal accounts bereikt.");
       } 
       });

       btnInloggen.setOnAction(e ->{
           for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
           {
          if ((user[c] == txtUsername.getText()) && (pas[c] == Password.getText())){
                  AlertBox.display("OKEE", "goed.");
                }
          else{
              AlertBox.display("Error", "NIET OK.");
            }
        }
       });


        VBox layout = new VBox();
        layout.getChildren().addAll(lblUsername,txtUsername,lblPassword,Password,btnAanmaken,btnInloggen);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


}
```

Comment: Use `String.equals` to compare strings

Comment: @Reimeus i edited it but i still can't log in :s. This is what i did: if ((txtUsername.equals(user[c])) && (Password.equals(user[c]))) {

Answer (score 0):

This condition will be never verified:

```
if ((user[c] == txtUsername.getText()) && (pas[c] == Password.getText())){
```

You cannot compare `String` by `==` but you have to use `equals`:

```
if (user[c].equals(txtUsername.getText() && pas[c].equals(Password.getText()){
```

Comment: i get the fallowing error:
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Login.lambda$start$1(Login.java:69)

Comment: @Satosho Kouno i edited it but i still can't log in :s. This is what i did: if ((txtUsername.equals(user[c])) && (Password.equals(user[c]))) {

Answer (score 0):

You have bad logic in your login.

At this line:

```
if (index < 10){
    index++;  
    user[index]=txtUsername.getText();
    pas[index]=Password.getText();

...
```

In this you are placing your login information in index 1 of the array.

So when you access it here:

```
for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
     if ((user[c].equals(txtUsername.getText())) && (pas[c].equals(Password.getText()))){
```

...

The record in position [0] is null.  This is why you are getting a NPE.

I am unsure as to why you are using a predefined array to handle this but you likely want to add the following to your loop:

```
if(user[c] == null) continue;
```

This way it will skip the null record.

You should also break from your loop when something is found:

```
 if ((user[c].equals(txtUsername.getText())) && (pas[c].equals(Password.getText()))){
     AlertBox.display("OKEE", "goed.");
     break;
}
```